# android Tablayout inside navigation fragment ActionBarDrawerToggle icon not there

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

navigation drawer with  fragments

1 - home
2 - courses
3 - gallery

i created 3 fragments for home,courses,gallery resp.
when app open home fragment is going to show

when i click on courses from navigation drawer coursesFragment will open within this fragment i created tab layout and tab layout is showing correctly as i needed, but drawer toggle icon is not there but drawer is opening when i pull it from left side

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home fragment");

        NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navview);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.Home:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home fragment");
                        item.setChecked(true);

                        break;
                    case R.id.gallery:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new GalleryFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("gallery fragment");
                        item.setChecked(true);

                        break;
                    case R.id.courses:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new CoursesFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("courses fragment");

                        item.setChecked(true);

                        break;
                }
                drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    tools:context="com.navdrawer.navdrawer.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/iso_main1"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

CoursesFragment.java :

```
public class CoursesFragment extends Fragment {



    public CoursesFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
          ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Download");

        TabLayout tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.courses_tabl);
        ViewPager viewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.courses_viewpager);

        ViewpagerAdapter viewpagerAdapter=new ViewpagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewpagerAdapter.addFragments(new DownloadFragment(),"Download");
        viewpagerAdapter.addFragments(new AlreadyDownlodedFragment(),"Downloaded");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewpagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }
```

fragment_courses.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.navdrawer.navdrawer.CoursesFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/courses_appbar_layout"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <include
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/courses_tabl"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"

            >

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/courses_viewpager"
        >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</FrameLayout>
```

here is my fragment_gallery.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.navdrawer.navdrawer.GalleryFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

GalleryFragment:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {


    public GalleryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    }

}
```

here is screenshots :

[image: homefragment]

[image: courses fragment]

[image: gallery fragment]

Comment: if i dont use tablayout into coursesFragment (removing all tablayout from xml and java) then everything is fine and  working when i add tab layout into xml and java then again its not working

Answer (score 1):

Can i see Gallery fragment's xml ?
BTW, why are you using a toolbar again in your courses fragment ?
This must be the issue.. Remove the toolbar from there as it must be overriding the parent activity's toolbar.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.navdrawer.navdrawer.CoursesFragment">



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/courses_tabl"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"/>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/courses_viewpager"/>
```

This is what you need here

Also make this change in your main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: galleryFragment.xml is not related with this issue why you wants to see that xml?

i tried this and action bar gone, in my style.xml im using this theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: am i need to remove appbar layout and toolbar from  courses fragment?

Comment: yes you do.. Thats useless there and simply increasing the loading time of layout

Comment: is there any working script similer to mine?

or similer to what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can set Home button as follows

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

add this line after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
If you want set your Custom Icon then you can set as follows

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.myhome);//pass id of your navigation icon
```

Comment: where should i write this?

((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

i tried like above but no luck

Comment: in you activity where you set your navigation drawer

Comment: my problem with corsesFragment see 2nd image

Comment: don not use tool bar in your Course Fragment use only tab layout. Your activity_main toolbar also work for this. just remove the toolbar from `course.xml` and fragment class  as well